# ssh not resolving updated CNAMES

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I have an alias for SSHing in to a specific machine.  The alias uses a hostname like so:

```
ssh user@example.com
```

Example.com is a CNAME.  For some reason, I can dig the hostname after I change the CNAME to point somewhere else, and it resolves correctly, but on the same machine, ssh thinks the CNAME is still the old location.  How do I get ssh to resolve the new CNAME correctly?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Had to do the following:

```
  sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```